# Issue with v-model + :value on input

Tags: vue.js

I wanna display the result of a API GET in a input text and also being able to modify the content of that input before sending it back to my API via a PUT route. But the following code is making a error.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="titre" :value="posts['titre_panneau']">
```

This is the error I got.

[image: I get this error]

Comment: Don't use v-model and value together, v-model holds value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is -

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="titre">
```

In your data property -

```
data () {
  return {
    titre: null
  }
}
```

And when you get your response just set the titre to the new value.

```
  methods: {
    getData () {
      this.GET('ENDPOINT').then(res => {
        this.titre = res.data.posts[titre_panneau]
      })
    }
  }
```

Let me know if it works!